# Get first word on every new line in a long string?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to add a leaderboard in my unity app
I have a long string as below(just an example, actual string is http pipe data from my web service, not manually stored):

```
string str ="name1|10|junk data.....\n
             name2|9|junk data.....\n
             name3|8|junk data.....\n
             name4|7|junk data....."
```

I want to get the first word (string before the first pipe '|' like name1,name2...) from every line and store it in an array and then get the numbers (10,9,8... arter the '|') and store it in an other one.
Anyone know  whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you have any algorithm in your mind? Like how would you do that manually if you were asked to do that as detailed as possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: I've only tried using "highScores.LastIndexOf('|')" to get the last character/player rank before, but haven't tried anything like this. The above string is pipe data of highscores returned from my server. I'm using it in a game I am working on. I was thinking of using regex, but was wondering if there is anything simpler.

Comment: Hint `String.Split()`.

Comment: this looks like homework, we can help, but you have to show that you are stuck with something specific. we all have jobs and time is limited, so we can't just do your homework for you

Comment: yeah, string.split is the function you need, it converts a string into an array

Comment: Homework?haha, no, this is for a unity app I am working on. Im trying to add a leaderboard and am not the best at regex or string alteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/utp4HK

code below, you may want to revisit the algorithm for performance, but if that is not an issue, this will do the trick;

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string str ="name1|10|junk data.....\nname2|9|junk data.....\nname3|8|junkdata.....\nname4|7|junk data.....";

        foreach (var line in str.Split('\n'))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line.Split('|')[0]);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked, and will come in handy later on. I'm only pulling data for top 10 users so performance shouldn't be an issue. I ended up using: `string str = line.Split('|')[0] +" :Score: "+ line.Split('|')[1]"` in the foreach loop to get the first 2 pieces of data and stored them into an array.

Answer (score 1):

First split by new-line characters:

```
string[] lines = str.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Then you can use LINQ to get both arrays:

```
var data = lines.Select(l => l.Trim().Split('|')).Where(arr => arr.Length > 1);
string[] names   = data.Select(arr => arr[0].Trim()).ToArray();
string[] numbers = data.Select(arr => arr[1].Trim()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link on splitting strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228388.aspx

You could first create an array of strings (one for each line) by splitting the long string with \n as the delimeter.

Then, you could split each line with | as the delimeter. The name would be the 0th index of the array and the number would be the 1st index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you *can't* have a multi line string without using [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). With using verbatim string literal, you can split your string based on `\r\n` or `Environment.NewLine` like;

```
string str = @"name1|10|junk data.....
               name2|9|junk data.....
               name3|8|junk data.....
               name4|7|junk data.....";
var array = str.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine},
                      StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
foreach (var item in array)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.Split(new[]{"|"},
                     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0].Trim());
}
```

Output will be;

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string str ="name1|10|junk data.....\n" +
                         "name2|9|junk data.....\n" +
                         "name3|8|junk data.....\n" +
                         "name4|7|junk data.....";

            string[] tempArray1 = str.Split('\n');
            string[] tempArray2 = null;

            string[,] newArray = null;


            for (int i = 0; i < tempArray1.Length; i++)
            {
                tempArray2 = tempArray1[i].Split('|');

                if (newArray[0, 0].ToString().Length == 0)
                {
                    newArray = new string[tempArray1.Length, tempArray2.Length];
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < tempArray2.Length; j++)
                {
                    newArray[i,j] = tempArray2[j];
                }
            }
```